# Count Consecutive Days where value greater than 0

Tags: sql-server, rank, gaps-and-islands

Using SQL Server 2012, I am trying create a query that provides me with, say, the top 10 longest wet (or dry) periods from a climate database.

My temp table provides the following data output:

```
select monthid as [id], date, rain_today 
from #raindays
order by monthid asc, date asc
```

Output:

```
id  date            rain_today
-------------------------------
1   24 Dec 2014     2.4
1   25 Dec 2014     0
1   26 Dec 2014     8.7
1   27 Dec 2014     1.8
1   28 Dec 2014     0.3
1   29 Dec 2014     0
1   30 Dec 2014     0
1   31 Dec 2014     0.3
2   01 Jan 2015     0.3
2   02 Jan 2015     0.3
2   03 Jan 2015     18.3
2   04 Jan 2015     0.3
```

etc. etc.

I would like to return a ranked table that would count the period where rain_today is > 0, (or rain_today = 0) i.e:

```
Rank Start_Date   End_Date    Wet Period
----------------------------------------
1    31 Dec 2014  04 Jan 2015 5
2    26 Dec 2014  28 Dec 2014 3
```

...

The closest I have got from reviewing other similar queries is the following (this is for dry days):

```
 select 
     #raindays.monthid as id,
     min(#raindays.date) as [FirstDryDay],
     max(#raindays.date) as [LatestDryDay],
     count(*) as countdays
 from 
     (select 
          monthid, 
          coalesce(max(case 
                          when rain_today > '0' 
                             then #raindays.date end), '19000101') as latestdry
     from 
         #raindays
     group by 
         monthid) g
join 
    #raindays on #raindays.monthid = g.monthid
              and #raindays.date > g.latestdry
group by 
    #raindays.monthid
order by 
    countdays desc
```

Output:

```
id  FirstDryDay     LatestDryDay    countdays
-----------------------------------------------
23  21 Oct 2016     31 Oct 2016     11
21  23 Aug 2016     31 Aug 2016     9
**15    23 Feb 2016     29 Feb 2016     7**
10  25 Sep 2015     30 Sep 2015     6
8   28 Jul 2015     31 Jul 2015     4
24  28 Nov 2016     30 Nov 2016     3
29  29 Apr 2017     30 Apr 2017     2
30  30 May 2017     31 May 2017     2
31  29 Jun 2017     30 Jun 2017     2
20  30 Jul 2016     31 Jul 2016     2
7   29 Jun 2015     30 Jun 2015     2
5   30 Apr 2015     30 Apr 2015     1
11  31 Oct 2015     31 Oct 2015     1
17  30 Apr 2016     30 Apr 2016     1
22  30 Sep 2016     30 Sep 2016     1
```

As you can see, I don't really want to group by id as I want to be able to span over different months and I'm missing other periods that occur earlier in the month. The actual count is working fine correctly it seems, checking above highlighted period:

```
id  date    rain_today
15  22 Feb 2016     3.9
15  23 Feb 2016     0
15  24 Feb 2016     0
15  25 Feb 2016     0
15  26 Feb 2016     0
15  27 Feb 2016     0
15  28 Feb 2016     0
15  29 Feb 2016     0
16  01 Mar 2016     3
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is your intended output?

Comment: It'd be very helpful for you to provide a ddl with populated temp data along with your expected output

Comment: If you're using 2012 or newer you could use window functions, a running total with something like `sum(case when rain_today > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by date)`

Comment: Sorry that's probably not so helpful, you most likely need more complex thing, with case 0 / 1 and something like row_number() for all the rows minus row_number() partitioned by that 0 / 1, and then group by that

Comment: What happens if you take out the group by monthid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want???

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    id INT NOT NULL ,
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
    Rain_Today DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL 
    );

INSERT #TestData (id, Date, Rain_Today) VALUES 
    (1, '24 Dec 2014', 2.4),
    (1, '25 Dec 2014', 0),
    (1, '26 Dec 2014', 8.7),
    (1, '27 Dec 2014', 1.8),
    (1, '28 Dec 2014', 0.3),
    (1, '29 Dec 2014', 0),
    (1, '30 Dec 2014', 0),
    (1, '31 Dec 2014', 0.3),
    (2, '01 Jan 2015', 0.3),
    (2, '02 Jan 2015', 0.3),
    (2, '03 Jan 2015', 18.3),
    (2, '04 Jan 2015', 0.3);

--======================================

WITH 
    cte_AddRankGroup AS (
        SELECT 
            td.id,
            td.Date,
            td.Rain_Today,
            hr.HasRain,
            RankGroup = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY td.id ORDER BY td.Date) -
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY td.id, hr.HasRain ORDER BY td.Date)
        FROM 
            #TestData td
            CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (IIF(td.Rain_Today = 0, 0, 1)) ) hr (HasRain)
        )
SELECT 
    arg.id,
    BegDate = MIN(arg.Date),
    EndDate = MAX(arg.Date),
    WetPeriod = IIF(arg.HasRain = 1, 'Wet', 'Dry'),
    ConsecutiveDays = COUNT(1)
FROM 
    cte_AddRankGroup arg
GROUP BY 
    arg.id,
    arg.HasRain,
    arg.RankGroup
ORDER BY 
    arg.id,
    MIN(arg.Date);
```

Results...

```
id          BegDate     EndDate     WetPeriod ConsecutiveDays
----------- ----------  ----------  --------- ---------------
1           2014-12-24  2014-12-24  Wet       1
1           2014-12-25  2014-12-25  Dry       1
1           2014-12-26  2014-12-28  Wet       3
1           2014-12-29  2014-12-30  Dry       2
1           2014-12-31  2014-12-31  Wet       1
2           2015-01-01  2015-01-04  Wet       4
```

Edit: Code version using CASE expression in place of IIF...

```
--======================================

WITH 
    cte_AddRankGroup AS (
        SELECT 
            td.id,
            td.Date,
            td.Rain_Today,
            hr.HasRain,
            RankGroup = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY td.id ORDER BY td.Date) -
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY td.id, hr.HasRain ORDER BY td.Date)
        FROM 
            #TestData td
            CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CASE WHEN td.Rain_Today = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ) hr (HasRain)
        )
SELECT top 10
    arg.id,
    BegDate = MIN(arg.Date),
    EndDate = MAX(arg.Date),
    WetPeriod = CASE WHEN arg.HasRain = 1 THEN 'Wet' ELSE 'Dry' END,
    ConsecutiveDays = COUNT(1)
FROM 
    cte_AddRankGroup arg
WHERE 
    arg.HasRain = '0' -- Top 10 Dry
    --arg.HasRain = '1' -- Top 10 Wet
GROUP BY 
    arg.id,
    arg.HasRain,
    arg.RankGroup
ORDER BY 
    ConsecutiveDays desc, MIN(arg.Date);
```

Modified original script to produce the Top 10 by each period type which was my ultimate aim (output is from the full dataset):

```
id  BegDate EndDate WetPeriod   ConsecutiveDays
31  10 Jun 2017     26 Jun 2017     Dry 17
4   02 Mar 2015     14 Mar 2015     Dry 13
5   12 Apr 2015     24 Apr 2015     Dry 13
20  15 Jul 2016     26 Jul 2016     Dry 12
29  01 Apr 2017     11 Apr 2017     Dry 11
26  17 Jan 2017     27 Jan 2017     Dry 11
23  21 Oct 2016     31 Oct 2016     Dry 11
25  01 Dec 2016     09 Dec 2016     Dry 9
21  10 Aug 2016     18 Aug 2016     Dry 9
21  23 Aug 2016     31 Aug 2016     Dry 9
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for helping...I'm getting incorrect syntax error on the two IIF lines...although they look ok to me: CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (IIF(td.Rain_Today = 0, '0', '1')) ) hr (HasRain)) - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Odd. I just retested against my copy of SQL Server 2012. Are you sure that's the version you're using?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server 2012. Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.2100.60

Comment: Well... The code I provided, as it's written, does execute in 2012. The fact that the snippet has single quotes and mine doesn't indicates that you've modified what I wrote. Start by executing the code, as provided (including the #TestData temp table) to verify that it works and then modify it as needed to fit your data model.

Comment: Yep, copied and pasted it exactly as provided and same error with the 'incorrect syntax near the '='. The table snippet works fine.

Comment: I'm testing w/ @@VERSION = Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-GDR) (KB3194721) - 11.0.6248.0 (X64)   Sep 23 2016 15:49:43   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) ... Same for you?

Comment: Updated answer to use a CASE expression in place of IIF.

Comment: CASE version works fine. Interesting...even though I'm in 2012 this is coming up: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
 Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) ---- I am going to clean up versions on my machine and just have 2012.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be resolved by recursion in this way:

```
-- this variable is needed to stop the recursion
declare @numrows int=(select count(1) from #raindays)

-- add a row number to the table creating a new table as "tabseq"
;WITH tabseq as (select row_number() over(order by date) as rownum, * from #raindays),
-- apply recursion to tabseq keeping a toggle running totals of wet and dry periods
CTE as
(
select *, 
 (case when rain_today=0 then 1 else 0 end) as dry,
 (case when rain_today>0 then 1 else 0 end) as wet 
from tabseq where rownum=1
union all 
select s.*,
 (case when s.rain_today=0 then cte.dry+1 else 0 end) as dry,
 (case when s.rain_today>0 then cte.wet+1 else 0 end) as wet
from tabseq s
join cte on s.rownum=cte.rownum+1
where s.rownum<=@numrows
)
select * from cte
```

Once you have the table (cte) with the dry/wet accumulators you can order and select from it to suit your output requirements.

Please note that this is assuming consecutive days on the table, if there are gaps then instead of adding +1 on the case statement you may need to add a datediff to one side or the other depending how you consider the missing dates (wet or dry).

Comment: thanks, ambiguous column name 'rain_today' @ 16 + 17?

Comment: let me know if you have more issues as when I wrote it i was unable to test it

Comment: I've noticed that there was a missing ) on the declare stmt too. This code should work assuming the table #raindays as per OP

Comment: Yes, I noticed the missing bracket. I also had to add the following line at the end of the query. option (maxrecursion 0). Having a look through the results now...

Comment: yes, correct, if you expect more than a 100 recursion level you need to put a limit or 0 for no limit